# vuejs transition callbacks issue on leave

Tags: javascript, vue.js, transition

I have this simple animation with vuejs, and I'm trying to update the component's internal state, on certain animation callbacks. My intention is to pass the property further down to children and trigger nested leave-transitions, but apparently, I can't get it to work.

- On appear/entering the callbacks work and the property is updated as expected.
- On leave, even though the callbacks are triggered and the property is indeed updated, the template won't react.

Snippet works, but here's a fiddle if needed http://jsfiddle.net/heyapo/bzor84a1/84/

```js
Vue.component('child-view', {
  template: '#child-view',
  data() {
    return {
      status: 'hidden',
    }
  },
  methods:{
    beforeEnter(el) {
      this.status = "will enter";
    },
    enter(el, done) {
      this.status = "entering";
      setTimeout(()=>{
       done();
      }, 1000);
    },
    afterEnter(el) {
      this.status = "entered";
    },
    beforeLeave(el) {
      this.status = "will leave";
    },
    leave(el, done) {
      this.status = "leaving";
      setTimeout(()=>{
       done();
      }, 1000);
    },
    afterLeave(el) {
   this.status = "hidden";
    }
  }
});

var demo = new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
 data: {
    showChild: false,
  },
  methods: {
   onClick: function(){
     this.showChild = !this.showChild;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity 2s
}
.fade-enter,
.fade-leave-to,
.fade-leave-active{
  opacity: 0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.min.js"></script>
<template id="child-view">
  <transition 
    appear
    name="fade"
    v-on:before-enter="beforeEnter"
    v-on:enter="enter"
    v-on:after-enter="afterEnter"
    v-on:before-leave="beforeLeave"
    v-on:leave="leave"
    v-on:after-leave="afterLeave"
  >
    <div>{{ status }}</div>
  </transition>
</template>
  
  
<div id="demo">
  <div >
    <child-view v-if="showChild"/>
  </div>
  <button v-on:click="onClick">
     toggle
  </button>
</div>
```